# Does the order of expressions or predicates make any difference in the join condition for outer joins in standard SQL with ANSI joins?

Tags: sql

Take a typical left outer join scenario. We all know that the order of the tables is quite significant, e.g., **Q1** and **Q2** are not equivalent:

```
SELECT A.x, B.y FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id -- (Q1)
SELECT A.x, B.y FROM B LEFT OUTER JOIN A ON B.id = A.id -- (Q2)
```

When I think conceptually about multiple joins it usually seems natural to me to imagine picking up the new table as the object of interest and then describing how its rows are related to what's come before. Keeping the terms in parallel doesn't have any advantage to me and by my own habit I generally write the join condition this way:

```
SELECT A.x, B.y FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id -- (Q3)
```

I had a conversation with a former coworker who misunderstood how the syntax works. To this coworker, **Q3** was wrong and **Q1** was right. And I do recognize that with the old-style outer join syntax this would matter and that's likely the source of this confusion. I've never heard or seen anyone else make this case using ANSI joins. Please answer this question and redeem my reputation, point out something I've overlooked, or offer deeper insight into the erroneous perspective.

*Does the order of expressions or predicates make any difference in the join condition for outer joins in standard SQL with ANSI joins?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it makes no difference.

Personally I prefer the style that you show in Q3, some of my workmates prefer the style in Q1. I don't know anyone who would ever consider either of them to be *wrong*.

The query optimiser turns the query inside out into something completely different, so the predicate doesn't even exist as a plain comparison any more when it's done with it. Usually it's a lookup in an index or a table, and as that can only be done in one direction, how the predicate was written makes no difference.

I checked (in SQL Server 2005) the execution plan of two queries with the predicate operands in different order, and as expected they are identical.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer Q3's JOIN's condition order too:

```
... ON B.id = A.id -- (Q3)
```

As it directly reflects that the B.id is the more varying one, you can think of A.id as the constant being tested against, e.g.

```
B.id = 1984
```

In the same vein that I don't want to see this in code...

```
1984 = B.id
```

...,like you I don't want to see this in query:

```
A.id = B.id
```

However, like most things in life, there are people who like little-endian, and there are those who like big-endian. Whatever mental model it may serve them on the preference they have chosen, they should be at least able to explain to you the rationale why they wanted `A.id = B.id`

I think, I have to switch my preference though, my(and your) preferred condition order doesn't work in some ORM, Linq in particular. I have yet to grasp why they impose that the condition should be in Q1's order:

```
from x in A
join y in B on x.id equals y.id
```

And reversing the condition (same as Q3, though in SQL query it is not an error) order results to syntax error, this won't be accepted by Linq:

```
from x in A
join y in B on y.id equals x.id
```

Now, I have to find the rationale why Microsoft Linq designers preferred the Q1 condition's order. And try to appreciate it if it makes sense, and just accept even it doesn't (yet) makes sense.

---

Regarding:

> Does the order of expressions or predicates make any difference in the
>   join condition for outer joins in standard SQL?

Results-wise, **NO**. Performance-wise, I have yet to see a query where the join's condition order makes the query faster. Even in forums I haven't seen anyone endorses reversing the condition to make the query faster.

If they can't explain to you the rationale or the mental model of their preferred condition's order serves, perhaps they are just doing [Cargo Cult Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) or worse yet, [Bikeshedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_Law_of_Triviality)

Comment: I've thought about Cargo Cult too. I had hoped to get my coworker to vocalize her thought process so I could pinpoint the confusion. There are blind people who profess a grave frustration with others who don't want to see and learn. I guess that's pretty much the same thing at the core and the direction I'm now leaning.

Comment: Here's another example: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/02/29/60542.aspx

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I wish it had specifically referred to outer join. I think the heart of the confusion is rooted in that concept.

Comment: Hmm.. probably :-) Maybe she thought when you do `A /*first*/ LEFT OUTER JOIN B /*second*/`, you should also do `ON A /*first*/.ID = B /*second*/.ID`. If she only know that the three(Oracle,Postgresql,MySQL) of the big four(Oracle,Sql Server,Postgresql,MySQL) supported this kind of JOIN: `A LEFT OUTER JOIN B USING(id)`, all her *perceived* correctness on specific condition order could all goes out of the window, Cargo Cult could be avoided. But alas, Sql Server don't want to join the party, hence those kind of confusion arises ツ

Comment: I'm 99% certain you are correct and I attempted to lead her toward actually stating her objection that way. I had to give it up because I didn't want to be too defensive about it. (Part me wanted to mention USING as well.) You hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the equality comparison makes no difference to the results of the join.  But it might for inscrutable reasons affect the efficiency with which the result is computed.  SQL optimizers are notorious for being affected by seemingly unimportant details like this.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer your Q1, however it makes *absolutely no difference* in performance and has absolutely no effect on the query optimizer.

To me, putting the previous table first gives me the relevant information sooner in my scanning process. I can read `join table B on A ...` and already know which two tables are being joined together. When I read `join table B on B.blasdjasdid = ...` I've had to scan much farther and still don't know the most important information, which table is being joined to (which is a sort of namespace, a domain under which the column name will be understood). Additionally, if the columns are named the same in both tables (idiomatic in any database I design), I can avoid scanning to the end entirely, reading only `join table B on A.SomethingId ...` and already knowing that it's `= B.SomethingId`.

Going a little deeper, I would encourage you to ask about this occurrence on [workplace.stackexchange.com](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) because I suspect that the reasons your services were discontinued do not match what they told you; some inquiry into this might be productive. I'm not suggesting it was your fault, but that the reason given was likely a pretext.

Comment: I got little feedback through the agency when they called to notify me; three and a half years later it's a mostly forgotten event. The company was an MLM so it was a questionable operation anyway. Since I was already working in a vacant office across the hall I simply walked away from the computer and spoke to no one on the way out. It was demoralizing experience during a rough period of my life, hence the cathartic question above where I just wanted everybody to pile on about how dumb she was. I've considered deleting it.

There might be some value in your suggestion so I'll think about it.